# Whats The Key Diffrence Between Request-Response and Push-Pull Service Model In Terms Of Network Or Website Application?

Tags: node.js, web-applications

Recently I did Start To Learn Node.js abd As of That i did Figure out that nower day`s node.js is widely use cause it supports Push-Pull/Publish-subscript as well as Request-Response both kind of Programming Capability.
But After Reading 6 to 8 article still i have confusion on the diffrance between them.

Any Help Would Be Appriciated.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple.

Lets assume the server has an update for the client.  For instance, the client receives a message.

In **request-response**, the client won't notice about that message until he will send a request to the server, using ajax or simply moving to another page (Executing Http request).

The main problem here is that the updates are not **real-time/live**. The client doesn't know if there are any updates for him until he make a further request.

On the other hand, in **push-pull** relation the sever **pushes** the updates to the client,
so the client informed about the message he receives **live**, without waiting for the next request to receive the update.

[Pull technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology) vs [Push technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) technologies explained in wikipedia.

Comment: so PUSH means Provide Response Without Getting Request, Directly To The Client. And PULL And Request are same. am I getting Right?

Comment: You are right, I've added wikipedia links that explain both pull and push technologies

Comment: Thanks I am Going To Accept Your Answer